# CPU increase after upgrading to JRE 64

Tags: java, tomcat7

I have a web application which is running under Tomcat7 with 32 bit JRE-7. I have upgraded it to 64 bit JRE to utilize more heap space as the application needs it. Both JRE and Tomcat are upgraded to 64 bit versions. I am seeing higher CPU utilization by the application after upgrade, the CPU utilization is gone up by 50%. Wanted to know if there are any known performance issues with JRE and Tomcat 64 bit version and any configuration parameters to be changed.

Comment: well, is your JRE doing GC? or some heavy processing? I/O? Btw - JRE7 is already end-of-life, if you're upgrading things, why not go directly to supported version?

Comment: maybe it was bottlenecked on 32bit and couldn't utilize all the cpu it needed?

Comment: 64 bit twice the size of 32 bit.

Comment: Stupid question: how many RAM You have on this machine?